# Where is /usr/share/zoneinfo specified?

Tags: directory, time, paths

We are adding timezone support to our Ubuntu application.

The time zone info on my machine is in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

> 1. Is it always in that directory? *If so, where is that specified*?
> 2. If not, is there system call similar to "gettimeofday(2)" that I can make to find out where it is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search location for the time zones is encoded in the C library (where the various time zone aware functions are found):

```
$ strings -a /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep zoneinfo
/usr/share/zoneinfo
```

The C library code makes use of this directory as a preprocessor `#define`, so there is no routine to ask what value it was compiled with.

If you need to parse the the time zone data yourself (as opposed to using the few C library routines available), then hard coding `/usr/share/zoneinfo` should be fine: if your target platforms follow the [Linux File System Hierarchy](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SPECIFICOPTIONS15), you should be safe.

If you are only interested in the local time zone, read `/etc/localtime`, which will be a copy of the relevant file from `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.